# How to convert Float to String in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

have a list with data as float or number and I need to convert it to String for comparison with robotframework with another dataset which is in String only.

I tried string operations from robotframework but I didn't find anything to convert float to String.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] to illustrate what you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Builtin keyword that does just that - `Convert To String`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20String), that will make any passed value to a string type.

Answer (score 4):

There is not always need to make conversions.

All of these assertions below work fine:

```
${float}=     Convert To Number    4.22
${string}=    Convert To String    4.22
Should Be Equal     '${float}'    '${string}'
Should Be Equal As Strings      ${float}    ${string}
Should Be Equal As Numbers      ${float}    ${string}
```